# Symfony 2 override entity field property

Tags: database, forms, symfony, entity

I want to override the entity field property. I need to get data from another database table (mapped by id). It should be a combination of "artikelnummer" and a field called "name" from another database table.

```
$builder->add('schlauch', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'SchlauchBundle:Artikelspezifikation',
    'property' => 'artikelnummer',
    'attr' => array(
      'class' => 'extended-select'
     ),
     'data_class' => null    
));
```

The field "artikelnummer" outputs something like "12345" but I need to add the name (from another database table called "schlauch"), so it should look like "12345 Articlename". I tried a query in the entity file, but I dont't want to manipulate the output everywhere.

Is it possible to use a query for property and override it?

Answer (score 0):

You can simple solve that by adding new getter to you entity:

```
class Artikelspezifikation
{
    //…

    /**
     * @var Schlauch
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Schlauch", inversedBy="artikelspezifikations")
     */
    private $schlauch;

    //…

    /**
     * Get display name
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDisplayName()
    {
        return $this->artikelnummer . ' ' . $this->schlauch->getArtikelName();
    }

    //…

    /**
     * Set schlauch
     *
     * @param \SchlauchBundle\Entity\Schlauch $schlauch
     *
     * @return Artikelspezifikation
     */
    public function setCategory(\SchlauchBundle\Entity\Schlauch $schlauch = null)
    {
        $this->schlauch = $schlauch;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get schlauch
     *
     * @return \SchlauchBundle\Entity\Schlauch
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->schlauch;
    }
}
```

And in your form class just change property:

```
$builder->add('schlauch', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'SchlauchBundle:Artikelspezifikation',
    'property' => 'displayName',
    'attr' => array(
      'class' => 'extended-select'
     ),
     'data_class' => null    
));
```

Comment: Thank you, for quick your answer. How do I get  "$this->schlauch" as an object? I only got the id.

Comment: I tried this, but it returns only the id and not the object. I did something before with ArrayCollection, and that worked. But only store the id in the database and get the full related entity doesn't work. In controller I can get everything but in the entity file it seems to be a problem.

Comment: Read something about [associantion between objects in Doctrine](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html).